# Is there a way to work with nested CollectionViews in Xamarin Forms with MvvmCross?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm building a page inside a Xamarin Forms/MvvmCross project, where I need multiple CollectionViews (at least, that's what I assume).
On top of the screen I have a horizontal CollectionView. Beneath this first View, I added a vertical CollectionView.
Problem: I want to scroll down on the page so the first CollectionView disappears and the second one is more visible (especially on small screens, where only the first item of the second CollectionView is visible on top of the page).
I would like the first and second CollectionView to scroll on the page as one unit. Some advice would be great!

So far I've tried to change the second (vertical) CollectionView into a bindable StackLayout, but the items won't appear and this approach feels wrong.

```
    <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                    <SearchBar
                        mvx:La.ng="Placeholder SearchBar"
                        Margin="0,0,0,30"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
                        CancelButtonColor="{StaticResource White}"
                        PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource White_30}"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}"/>
                    <Label mvx:La.ng="Text Artists" FontFamily="FiraSans#600" FontSize="16" TextColor="#FF6C6E81" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
                    <CollectionView
                        x:Name="MyCollectionView"
                        ItemsSource="{mvx:MvxBind FavoriteArtists}"
                        HeightRequest="250" >

                        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                VerticalItemSpacing="1"
                                HorizontalItemSpacing="10" />
                        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                        <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <ActivityIndicator Color="DimGray" IsRunning="True" HeightRequest="50" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </CollectionView.EmptyView>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <templates:FavArtistsTemplate/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>

                    <Label mvx:La.ng="Text Recent" FontFamily="FiraSans#400" FontSize="14" TextColor="#FF6C6E81" Margin="0,0,0,8"/>

                    <CollectionView
                        x:Name="MyCollectionView2"
                        ItemsSource="{mvx:MvxBind RecentlyPlayedItems}">

                        <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <ActivityIndicator Color="DimGray" IsRunning="True" HeightRequest="50" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </CollectionView.EmptyView>

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <templates:MediaItemTemplate/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

I would like the first and second CollectionView to scroll on the page as one unit. Some advice would be great!

Comment: Typically when you build a native mobile app, to achieve this behavior what you do is build a ListView / Tableview (which is your vertical CollectionView), and then create another list/tableview (horizontal), that you assign as your first ListView/Tableview **header**. But to be honest I've not done enough work with the CollectionView to know if it is capable of handling this kind of Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put 2 horizontal `CollectionViews` in the `ListView` Header in a `Grid` or `StackLayout` :)

To be more clear:

Instead of 2 horizontal `CollectionViews` and 1 vertical `CollectionView`, you use 2 horizontal `CollectionViews` and 1 `ListView` (which is only vertical). In the Header of the `ListView`, you put the 2 horizontal `CollectionViews` in a `Grid` or `StackLayout`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#headers-and-footers